# Ruby on Rails: uninitialized constant UserController::ReportUserMailer

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, actionmailer

I have following method is **UserController**

```
def report_user
  current_user = User.find_by(id: params[:id])
  unless current_user.nil?
    ReportUserMailer.report_user_email(user, params).deliver_now
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

And in **mailers/report_mailer.rb** . I have following code.

```
class ReportUserMailer < ApplicationMailer

   layout "layouts/mailer"

  def report_user_email(currentUser, params)
    @user = currentUser
    @first_name = params[:first_name]
    @last_name = params[:last_name]
    @email = params[:current_user_email]
    @report_user_first_name = params[:report_user_first_name]
    @report_user_id = params[:report_user_id]
    @message = params[:message]
    if Rails.env.production?
      mail(to: "something@email.com", subject: "User Report")
    else
      mail(to: "something@email.com", subject: "User Report ")
    end
  end
end
```

When I make a post request to UserConroller. I get following error.

> NameError (uninitialized constant UserController::ReportUserMailer):

Mailer file name and class name are different but I can't modify file name or mailer code.

What am I missing here?

**EDIT:**

I can't modify the code as It is already being used as API.
I need a workaround to call mailer class without changing file name.

Comment: You're not "missing" anything, you seem to be aware of the problem and its solution: "Mailer file name and class name are different".

Comment: This is a legacy code used as API. I can not modify it. 
I need a workaround to access ``ReportUserMailer`` class without changing filename.

Comment: @WaqarHassan what do you mean you can't modify it aren't you working on it? Doesn't that require modification? you can always `require` the file in the `UserController`. e.g. `require Rails.root.join('app','mailers','report_mailer.rb')`

Comment: ``require`` was what I needed. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails expects the file to be named `report_user_mailer.rb`. If can't you modify the file name (why?) you'll need to manually `require` the file `mailers/app/report_mailer.rb`, like this:

```
class SomeClass < ActiveRecord

 require "#{RAILS_ROOT}/mailers/report_mailer.rb"

#your code that uses the ReportUserMailer class
end
```

Comment: It is legacy code being already used as API.
So, I can't modify it.

Comment: Ok, so if it wasn't clear from my post, I've edited it with an example.

Comment: Thanks. ``require`` worked.